# VM did not get added to Host pool when created from a Generalized gallery Image

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Created a Host pool with a VM in it and then created a Generalized image of that VM when I tried to create a new VM with that generalized image the VM got created but did not get added to the Host pool session host.

Steps followed to create a generalized image:

1. Installed all available updates.
2. Run Disk Cleanup.
3. Leave the Azure AD
4. Removed the VM from the Host Pool
5. Run Sysprep to Generalize the VM
6. Captured an Image in the Compute Gallery.

Create VM form Gallery image.

Comment: What is your question? You tell us what you did, but not what happened, and what y0ou expected to happen instead. See [ask].

Comment: Hi, @Robert My question is why VM did not get added to the Host pool session host in the Azure virtual desktop (AVD) when created using a custom gallery image. What I did steps are mentioned above. What did not happen is The VM got created but did not get added to the session host of the Host pool in AVD. I expected that The VM created using a custom gallery image should be added to the session host of the Host pool at the time of VM creation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may occur due to many reasons when a new vm created from a generalized image doesn't get added to an Azure Virtual Desktop host pool session host.

- Don't capture a VM that already exists in your host pools. The image will conflict with the existing VM's configuration, and the new VM won't work. Ensure to remove the VM from the domain before running sysprep.
- The new VM may not be added to the host pool due to incorrect configuration settings in the image or host pool. Sometime due to network issue pool may not be able to reach the VM effectively.

Created host pool and virtual machine using bastion `generalize` and shutdown the vm like below:

[image]

Capture the virtual machine :

[image]

Now in virtual desktop go to host pool -> Total machine -> click `add` in session host -> in virtual machine add image like below:

[image]

Now old vm as removed automatically in host pool added new vm in session host like below:

[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/set-up-golden-image?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004795